# overlays affine transform in google map

Tags: google-maps, affinetransform

In google map,there is a map type named `45 degree`.

So if I have some overlays like markers,circles in the normal layer,then if I change the map type to `45 degree`,then how about the overlays?

I think they should  be affine-transformed at the same time. But how to make it?

Comment: Google maps doesn't transform the map plane, it transforms the camera. There is no problem with transformation

Comment: When they transform the camera,then the shapes of the overlays should be transformed accordingly,isn't it?

Comment: They already transform, you just need to try it. What is your actual question?

Comment: Hi,kaya. I found that they indeed transform them. Then I want to know how did they make it? I do not mean their exact solution but the idea. :)